# How do you get the number that is in the center of numbers entered in a textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

For example I entered the numbers "31572" in a textbox then it will get the number "5". Also if I enter numbers with the length of even numbers like "123752" then it will get the "37" which is in the center of the entered numbers. I have no idea what to with this, so I'm hoping someone gives me an idea. Thank you :)

Comment: The easiest way is to convert the number to a string, and then use [string-manipulation instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to take from the string 2 chars when the string length is even and 1 char when it's odd, you just need to care about the remainder of the division by 2.

Using Integer division (`3 \ 2 = 1`):
If `String.Length Mod 2 = 0`, take 2 chars, starting from `String.Length \ 2 - 1`
If `String.Length Mod 2 = 1`, take 1 chars, starting from `String.Length \ 2`

You may want to add a null check and just return the original string if the string length is less than 3 (when the string is `"1"` or `"12"`, return the string as it is).
Your code could be:

```
Dim result as string = GetCenterValue(TextBox1.Text)
```

```
Public Function GetCenterValue(content As String) As String
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(content) Then Return String.Empty
    Dim sLength As Integer = content.Length
    If sLength < 3 Then Return content
    Return content.Substring(sLength \ 2 - (1 - sLength Mod 2), 2 - sLength Mod 2)
End Function
```

Comment: Mr. Jimi, what if I want to get the the alternating values of the textbox and group them? For example I enter the numbers "31572" then it will group the numbers 3, 5, and 2 and it will group the numbers 1 and 7, so the grouped numbers are 352 and 72, they will be separate groups. How do you do this? Hehe

Comment: It's more or less the same thing, you'll just have to parse the string char by char or use LINQ to `Select`/`Where` the even/odd positions. But this is another question, it cannot be answered here. Make another one (always showing what you tried to get the result). Btw, you didn't mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

As the content of the TextBox object is a text, simply take the text, check its length: if it's an even number halves that number and take that character and the following, if not, halves that number, round it up and take that character only. To check if a number is even use `Mod` operator (`n Mod 2`), if the result is 0 the number is even. Remember that `Substring` uses 0-based index.